# Ant: Importing specific environment variables

Tags: ant, path, environment-variables

A quick question, but probably one that doesn't have an answer (or at least an answer I want):

I want to only import a specific set of environment variables into an Ant script. I know I can import the entire environment via the `<property environment="env"/>` task. However, I'm using Jenkins and it just seems silly to import the whole environment because I want a couple of variables like `$BUILD_NUMER` and `$JOB_NAME`

I know I could do something like this:

```
 $ ant -DBUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER package
```

I thought someone might have figured out a way to do this via a resource collection. If not, I'll just have to accept the fact that all environment variables are imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly cheating ... use a [`scriptdef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html)?

```
<scriptdef name="envproperty" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="fromenv" />
<![CDATA[
    importClass( java.lang.System );
    project.setProperty(
        attributes.get( "name" ),
        System.getenv( attributes.get( "fromenv" ) )
    );
]]>
</scriptdef>

<envproperty name="BUILD_NUMBER" fromenv="BUILD_NUMBER" />
<envproperty name="JOB_NAME" fromenv="JOB_NAME" />
```